# Oracle DB doesn't return result when the query inputs contain German Characters

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I ran in to an issue today on my Oracle DB.

I have a deployed application and in one of the use case a query similar to the below is fired:

```
select * from t_my_table where col_name like '%Häntema%';
```

To make the selection ignore cases, the query is coded as :

```
select * from t_my_table where UPPER(col_name) like UPPER('%Häntema%');
```

The data string is not hardcoded, rather the Hibernate params are set to toUpperCase();

The strange part now is if I run this code from Eclipse as a Java app in Spring Boot environment, I find the required results. However, the same code deployed on the Tomcat pointing to the same database returns empty result set.

The results are however fetched if I change the query to avoid the German characters, i.e.

```
select * from t_my_table where UPPER(col_name) like UPPER('%ntema%');
```

will fetch the required results. So the issue is only with such characters.

Also when running the query directly on the SQL developer, they are always working.

What possibly can be going wrong here. I honestly have no clue to try something out. Can someone please suggest any solutions.

Comment: Did you check the collation of your DB?

Comment: what have you set in NLS_LANG?

Comment: What is the server-side (DB) character set?  What is the client-side character set, for each of the different clients?

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak: The DB character set is AL32UTF8. I am not sure what you mean by Client-side character set. Currently, I have an Angular based web-application as the client and I am testing it in Chrome.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, by "client-side" character set, I mean, what character set is used in the client?  How are you telling Oracle SQL\*Net about it?  SQL\*Net will do any necessary conversion correctly, if you have the NLS_LANG environment variable correctly set in the client.  Oracle needs to know what character set the client is using, to make the correct conversion.